# Downloading dependencies from a secured remote repository

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to download dependencies from a remote repository which requires authentication. Is there a way to provide credentials in my pom configuration? Thank you

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>alfresco-private</id>
        <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/private</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't beacuse POM is a 'public artifact' that you could share with 
your development team so it should not contains passwords.

> "The repositories for download and deployment are defined by the repositories and distributionManagement elements of the POM. However, certain settings such as username and password should not be distributed along with the pom.xml. This type of information should exist on the build server in the settings.xml."

Read here: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @Cisco's answer, you would put something like this in your own local `settings.xml`:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>alfresco-private</id>
        <username>H-H</username>
        <password>H-HsPassword</password>
    </server>
    ...
```